# Getting same sequence number from sequence object

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Is it possible that the SQL command `select next value for 'sequence_object'` executed from two application for one SQL database at the same time returns the same sequence number?
(I use Azure SQL database v12)

Comment: According to the documentation, I believe the answer is "yes" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx). Shockingly so.  To get uniqueness, you essentially need to have an identity column in a table, insert a row, and read the value from there.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790161/next-value-for-sequence-can-fail-to-return-proper-next-value

Comment: Fixes for SQL2012 SP2 and SQL2014: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3011465

Comment: Just to be clear, the documentation meets the ANSI standard and is designed to never return the same sequence number at the same time by competing processes. That would defeat the purpose of the sequence. However, there was a known issue with SQL Server when the server is under memory pressure, which is often a serious problem in itself.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you misread documentation. It stated that column with values populated based on sequence is not guaranteed to have only unique values as you can still insert values manually - identity columns are protected by design.

Answer (score 0):

No, and if it does it's a bug.

[Sequence Numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx)

The documentation referenced in the comments above is pretty clear. The only time you are going to get the same value out of a sequence is when the sequence resets itself and starts over at the beginning.